# How to get dependency called from Junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependencies

For my project, I would like to know how to get list of method-level dependency called from each Junit test method(@Test method). In other words, I would like to know list of method used in each Junit test. I would appreciate if you let me know any tools for it.

Comment: You want to know all methods invoked by a test method? Sounds like you need a profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'd like to have a method oriented coverage report.

I don't think there is any tool that does exactly what you need. But using a tool such as JaCoCo and running tests independently (which will take a while) you might be able to analyze results and get a list of called methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is JaCoCo possible to see the code coverate for each test method?

Comment: @jasonlee27 Unfortunately no. I am almost certain there is no tool that gives coverage/cpu profile per unit test. If you would find a way to communicate with coverage/cup profiling agent in runtime, then you might be able to get the data you need using JUnit extension. Otherwise, you would need to run each test separately and analyze result after each test (that's why I wrote it would take a while). If you could tell us why you need those methods, maybe we could suggest another solution.

Comment: I am working on finding relatedness of test method and source code method. for example, if one test method is not testing one source code method, then it is related, otherwise, it is not related.